# How the Express router's function app.use(path, require path) works?

Tags: javascript, api, express, path, routes

I work on a MERN tutorial currently.

[You can see on the video](https://youtu.be/BNikS1X5NVk?t=11m43s) that there is a function app.use('/api', require('./routes/api.js'));  which is used.

In fact this function is in an app.js file and lead to an another file place in a /routes/api.js path. But I don't understand why we got to use 'require' and why there is a repetition of the path  - /api , to /routes/api.js -

I have difficulties to understand how this function work. If someone can explain to us more in details it would be very great,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video he is using

```
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api.js'));
```

to say that if we navigate to:

```
${baseUrl}/api
```

load in the module api.js. That is what the require is doing. It is looking in the current directory notated by `./` and then going into the routes folder and loading the file api.js. In `api.js` he has a few things specified so that when we navigate to `/api` we can access the functions and/or routes located in `api.js`.

If you want to read up more about it check out: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use